# Cant find document data in Firestore, returns null

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-fragments, google-cloud-firestore

I cant seem to put text into a TextView. The data is comming from a Firestore databse. When i run it, the TextView is blank and returns a null. Below is what i've done so far. Could someone please take a look at it ? You can see my database structure here:[Picture of database structure][1]

```
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {

    TextView firstNameText, age;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
        firstNameText = rootView.findViewById(R.id.profile_firstName);
        age = rootView.findViewById(R.id.profile_age);
        getUserInfo();

        return rootView;

    }

    public void getUserInfo() {
        db.collection("Users").document(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail()).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                    DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = task.getResult();
                    String firstName = documentSnapshot.getString("Firstname");
                    Log.d(TAG, "Printing docData: " + documentSnapshot.getData());
                    firstNameText.setText(firstName);

                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot.

Comment: @AlexMamo Thanks, i have added the picture.

Comment: does you code goes inside success response? or failure? what logs shows ? What isnide Task object of response?

Comment: Is it something printed out in the logcat when using this line of code `Log.d(TAG, "Printing docData: " + documentSnapshot.getData());`?  Please also respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: could you share the log? and the content of documentSnapshot

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that

```
mAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail()
```

is the issue here.Try putting the user's e-mail in a String

```
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
     final FirebaseUser theUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
     if (theUser !=null)
     String UID = theUser.getEmail().toString();
```

And replace

```
 mAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail()
```

with UID .